# How to change given date in R?

Tags: r, date

I started working in R and need to change a date. On my search I only found how to change the format or setting the day/month/year to a specific number.
I have for example:

`my_date = as.Date("2020-03-01")`

in my algorithm I need to change this by one day. For this special case I am looking for

`2020-02-29`

Thanks for your answers.

Best
Felix

Comment: Can you try `my_date - 1`

Comment: oh man.. thank you and sorry.. I hought that I already tried this... ... obviously not

Answer (score 0):

I would propose to use `lubridate` library.

Then:

```
library(lubridate)
date <- ymd("2020-03-01")
date - days(1)
```

gives you "2020-02-29".